# Problem with Computer Modern

Tags: fonts, computer-modern

The text when I use Computer Modern doesn't look good, but the equations are fine

[image]

I don't know the problem. Can anybody help me?

I have this when I use overleaf[image]

Comment: you are using miktex but haven't installed the cm-super package perhaps? (if you mean that the text is jagged/pixelated, it is hard to tell from your image)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The text is pixelated. And I believe that I have installed the cm-super package perhaps

Comment: Is the top image the PDF view through a stand-alone PDF viewer (like Adobe) and the bottom what you see when viewing the PDF on Overleaf?

Comment: Yes the first is from Adobe and the last from Overleaf

Comment: show the list of fonts that the adobe reader font menu shows.

Comment: I forgot say that in the last picture I downloaded the pdf from Overleaf and I open with Adobe

Comment: I would guess that the font menu shows type 3 fonts in use, and that would imply that cm-super is not in use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used Texstudio in the first picture and I just used Texmaker and the text look good

Comment: Maybe the type 1 fonts database was not updated. Try running MiKTeX console, open the `Tasks` menu and click on `Refresh font map files` (both as administrator and as user)

Comment: texstudio and texmaker are just editors used to write the file. neither makes a pdf which is the underlying tex system, but you may have two installed one with and one without cm-super. You still haven't shown the font list in the pdf so can not say for sure.

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}` should also fix this.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you, this works for me

Comment: @Davislor for some definition of fix. "My car is broken, can you fix it", "yes use the bus".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I’m guessing you’d agree that Latin Modern is very, very similar?

Comment: @Davislor Cam you please make your suggestion to answer? Hope this may be one of an important point for some one...

Comment: @Davislor sure but it doesn't actually answer the question. The user has a sub-optimal local computer modern configuration and (for example) that will affect many tex documents that they get from elsewhere, that should be easily fixed by installing cm-super. Just saying don't use computer modern is avoidance rather than fix (even if it works well)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, and I made sure to address that in the first sentence of my answer. However, other people had already mentioned that, and I didn’t want to repeat what they had said, just add something new.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very good point about behing able to compile existing documents that use the default font. I added that to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The issue (as others have mentioned) is that you don’t have [the `cm-super` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) installed in MikTeX.  It’s falling back to old-style METAFONT files, which compile to pixelated bitmaps.

There are several other versions of Computer Modern that you can load instead.  In PDFTeX, you can load the Type 1 version of Latin Modern with `\usepackage{lmodern}`.  In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load the OpenType version of Latin Modern with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, or New Computer Modern with `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}`

If that.s more options than you were looking for, my advice would be to load New Computer Modern in LuaLaTeX. It has the widest repertoire of glyphs, and gives you the option to select a slightly-thicker weight. But (as David Carlisle wisely mentioned in his comment) please do still install `cm-super` so that any documents you download compile correctly.

Comment: +1  (despite the bus comment under the question:-)